# how to iterate map of maps to the widgets using flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I have a list of dynamic objects, how can I iterates this map to dataTable in flutter.

the map I have is something like this

```
    theList
    [1]:Map (9 items)
        0:"id" -> "1345"
        1:"count" -> "1"
        2:"FIRST_NAME" -> " ali "
        3:"SECOND_NAME" -> "hu"
        7:"added_in" -> "2016-11-30"
        9:"DESIGNATION" -> Map (1 item)
    [2]:Map (9 items)
        0:"id" -> "2345"
        1:"count" -> "1"
        2:"FIRST_NAME" -> " salam "
        3:"SECOND_NAME" -> "WON HO"
        7:"added_in" -> "2016-11-30"
        9:"DESIGNATION" -> Map (1 item)
    [3]:Map (9 items)
        0:"id" -> "3"
        1:"count" -> "1"
        2:"FIRST_NAME" -> " zaid "
        3:"SECOND_NAME" -> "raja"
        7:"added_in" -> "2016-11-30"
        9:"DESIGNATION" -> Map (1 item)
    [4]:Map (9 items)
        0:"id" -> "4345"
        1:"count" -> "1"
        2:"FIRST_NAME" -> " RI "
        3:"SECOND_NAME" -> "karam"
        7:"added_in" -> "2016-11-30"
        9:"DESIGNATION" -> Map (1 item)
```

and I using this code trying to do what I want

```
   SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: DataTable(
        sortAscending: true,
        sortColumnIndex: 0,
  columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("First Name"),
      numeric: false,
      tooltip: "To display first name of the Name",
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Last Name"),
      numeric: false,

      tooltip: "To display last name of the Name",
    ),
  ],
  rows: thelist
      .map(
        (name) => DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(name['REFERENCE_NUMBER'].toString()),
                  showEditIcon: false,
                  placeholder: false,
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(thelist[0]['REFERENCE_NUMBER'].toString()),
                  showEditIcon: false,
                  placeholder: false,
                )
              ],
            ),
      )
      .toList()),)
```

and stacked on this for three days and I get this error (type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'int of 'index')

any help is very appreciated

Comment: Better parse your data to typed objects. If you format your data, may be we can help.

Comment: your code is either not clear , or the error that you'v mentioned is not in this segment  , please edit the code and post the relevant lines of the error from the stack trace.